# CPLEX warm start error when using OPL model in Java API

Tags: java, cplex, opl

I am trying to do a warm start using the Java API and having some issues when passing the initial solution to the model.
In my model file(.mod) I have a 2D decision variable defined as,

```
range nodes = 1..5;
range vehicles = 1..2;
dvar int service_time[nodes][vehicles];
```

In my java file I am building the model as below and trying to pass an initial solution to the above decision variable using the addMipStart() function (as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_addMIPStart)),

```
static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    int status = 127;

    try {

        IloOplFactory.setDebugMode(true);
        IloOplFactory oplF = new IloOplFactory();
        IloOplErrorHandler errHandler = oplF.createOplErrorHandler(System.out);
        IloOplModelSource modelSource = oplF.createOplModelSource(DATADIR + "/myModFile.mod");
        IloOplSettings settings = oplF.createOplSettings(errHandler);
        IloOplModelDefinition def = oplF.createOplModelDefinition(modelSource, settings);

        IloCplex cplex = oplF.createCplex();
        IloOplModel opl = oplF.createOplModel(def, cplex);

        //adding the custom data source
        IloOplDataSource dataSource = new VRPDataSource(oplF);
        opl.addDataSource(dataSource);

        //generating the model
        opl.generate();

        //creating the initial solution
        int i = 5;
        int j = 2;

        IloIntVar[][] var2D = new IloIntVar[i][];
        double[][] var2D_startingVals = new double[i][];

        for(int index1=0; index1 < i; index1++){
            var2D[index1] = new IloIntVar[j];
            var2D_startingVals[index1] = new double[j];

            for(int index2 = 0; index2 < j; index2++){
                String varName = "service_time("+ (index1+1) +")("+ (index2+1) +")";
                var2D[index1][index2] = cplex.intVar(0, 50, varName);

                //lets assume a unit matrix as the starting solution
                var2D_startingVals[index1][index2] = 1;
             }
         }

        //flatten the multi-dimensional IloNumVar and double arrays

        IloNumVar[] flat_var2D = new IloNumVar[i*j];
        double[] flat_var2D_startingVals = new double[i*j];
        for(int index1=0; index1 < i; index1++){
            for(int index2=0; index2 < j; index2++){
                flat_var2D[index1*j + index2] = var2D[index1][index2];
                flat_var2D_startingVals[index1*j + index2] = var2D_startingVals[index1][index2];
            }
        }

        // adding the MIPStart
        cplex.addMIPStart(flat_var2D, flat_var2D_startingVals, IloCplex.MIPStartEffort.Auto, "addMIPStart start");

        if(cplex.solve()){
            // more code
        }else{
            // more code
        }

        // more code

    }catch(Exception ex){
        // more code
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately I am having an exception in the line which calls the cplex.addMIPStart() function as,**

```
 [java]     ### CONCERT exception: The referenced IloExtractable has not been extracted by the IloAlgorithm
 [java]     ilog.concert.IloException: The referenced IloExtractable has not been extracted by the IloAlgorithm
 [java]     at ilog.cplex.cppimpl.cplex_wrapJNI.IloCplex_addMIPStart__SWIG_0(Native Method)
 [java]     at ilog.cplex.cppimpl.IloCplex.addMIPStart(IloCplex.java:866)
 [java]     at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.addMIPStart(IloCplex.java:13219)
 [java]     at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.addMIPStart(IloCplex.java:13228)
 [java]     at myJavaClass.myJavaClass.main(myJavaClass.java:412)
```

**I am thinking the error is due to the way I prepare the initial solution, can somebody please help me to sort this out.**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating *new* variables, not referencing the existing variables in the model. These new variables do not exist in the objective, constraints, etc., so you get the `IloException` (see [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400028) technote).

You should be able to access the existing variables doing something like the following (*note that this code has not been tested*):

```
    IloIntRange nodes = opl.getElement("nodes").asIntRange();
    IloIntRange vehicles = opl.getElement("vehicles").asIntRange();
    IloIntVarMap serviceTime = opl.getElement("service_time").asIntVarMap();

    final int nbNodes = nodes.getSize();
    final int nbVehicles = vehicles.getSize();

    IloNumVar[] startX = new IloNumVar[nbNodes * nbVehicles];
    double[] startVals = new double[nbNodes * nbVehicles];
    for (int i = 0; i < nbNodes; i++) {
       IloIntVarMap inner = serviceTime.getSub(nodes.getValue(i));
       for (int j = 0; j < nbVehicles; j++) {
          int idx = i * nbVehicles + j;
          startX[idx] = inner.get(vehicles.getValue(j));
          startVals[idx] = 1.0;
       }
    }

    cplex.addMIPStart(startX, startVals);
```

Take a look at the [Iterators.java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/examples/html/opl_interfaces/java/iterators/src/iterators/Iterators.java.html) example and the documentation for [getElement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjavaopl/html/ilog/opl/IloOplModel.html?view=kc#getElement(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.

Since "service_time" is a decision variable I am getting an error as,

     [java] ### CONCERT exception: Type dvar int[nodes][vehicles] expected for element "service_time".
     [java]     at ilog.opl.IloOplElement.cpp_asNumVarMap(IloOplElement.java:506)

Also the addMIPStart() function is expecting  IloNumVar[] type of an array as var array. Any suggestion to overcome this?

Comment: I changed the snippet to use an `IloIntVarMap` for `serviceTime` instead of an `IloNumVarMap`. Does that fix it for you?